# I created an xcode project with the same name and I accidentally overwrote the old project

Tags: xcode

I created an xcode project with the same name and I accidentally overwrote the old project. How do I get it back? All old source is gone and it isn't in the Trash. It has all been replaced with the new project template code.

Comment: You _do_ have backups and source control, **right**?

Comment: I'm at a company and it is against policy to have USB hardrives for timemachine :(. One of those burrocratic jokes. We also use TFS so I have to open up Eclipse and remember to shelve it periodically. I lost 2 days work. Oh well.

Comment: Your company doesn't back up your machines? _Why not?_

Comment: Our macs are the first in a building with 800 PCs. The PC guys have clumsy backup scripts. They don't have an option for Macs here yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you have backups/source control, you can re-sync your old version.

Back up/shelve what you have now, and leave it checked out/on your system.  Then, try to replace just the project file(s), leaving your source code and data in-place.  Re-do the changes to your project(s), and you will have undone the damage.

- If you don't have source control or backups, and you didn't delete your code/data, you may still be in luck.  You'll have to re-create your project files from scratch, rather than your last save point, but you can simply import your existing code.
- If you don't have any of those, and you deleted the source, then you are out of luck

No matter what, your next step is to get and use source control and/or start doing *automatic* backups of your code.  Everyone makes mistakes like this, and this is why source control/backups exist.  You must use them.

Comment: XCode should not have deleted the source, he should be able to drag it back into the new project.  But the easiest way is to restore the project from a system backup OR from git, there is simply no excuse for not using at least one of those even with the smallest projects.

Comment: @Kendall: I agree with all this.  I don't use xcode, so I didn't make assumptions that it doesn't delete the folders when you create a new project.  Since it seems like it *does* work like everything else, I fixed the wording.

Comment: It did. It asked me "Do you want to overrite the old project" and I'm 99% positive I clicked no, but I think I bumped the return key. It deleted all the source and replaced it with the new project template.

Comment: Also, old source was not in recycle bin.

Comment: @Mike: It also deleted the files from within that directory?  It seems odd that it would throw out the contents of the folders, rather than just overwrite the project files, and maybe the boiler-plate source files.  Unless all your source was in the boilerplate files...

Comment: @Merlyn: Unfortunately I can see potentially how XCode might have destroyed the source - since in OS X when you copy a folder (using Finder) onto a folder of the same name, it replaces the old folder.  If that is what happened (instead of XCode just seeing if Classes exists and using an existing one if there) then it could have deleted the source.

Comment: Yes Merlyn it deleted all old files in all subfolders. My subfolders were also different from the auto generated ones too so I thought they might have been safe. But no!

Answer (score 0):

From the other discussion, it sounds like your best hope might be an OS X undelete utility, one example:

http://www.prosofteng.com/products/data_rescue.php

I hope you've not been doing much with the drive though as any file, email, or anything else you've saved to disk could have been overwriting what used to be there.  But, it's better than doing nothing.

I would boot off a separate drive before you downloaded that to run it.